# Adding a string to a variable in a Tailwind utility class

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to add a variable to a className and need to append a percentage for it to work. For example the following works:

```
className="scale-x-[35%]"
```

But the following doesn't:

```
className={`scale-x-[${variableNumber}%]`}
```

What would be the correct way to append the percentage string to my variable?

**Edit: Full code**

```
export default function proposalDetail() {
  const [percentage1, setPercentage1] = useState(10);
  const [percentage2, setPercentage2] = useState(35);
  return (
    <div className="relative p-4 my-4 overflow-hidden border border-gray-200 rounded-lg hover:border-indigo-500">
      <div className={`scale-x-${percentage1}% absolute inset-0 w-full origin-top-left bg-indigo-500 bg-opacity-50`}></div>
      <div className="relative text-black z-100 dark:text-white">
      <div className="font-medium">0% burn, 2.5% revenue</div>
      <div className="text-sm">23 voters</div>
      <div className="text-sm">295.7513474746361 QNTFI ({percentage1}%)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: I don't see a problem here. can you post the whole code snippet? maybe variableNumber is `undefined`. Also, are you using Tailwind css? If so, you don't need the square brackets, just ``scale-x-${variableNumber}%``

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work" do you mean on initial render or on when your var updates?

Comment: @jmargolisvt initial render

Comment: @KarimElghamry added whole code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`` className={`scale-x-${percentage1}% ...`} `` is an attempt to use a dynamic Tailwind utility class. This will not work because Tailwind creates its compiled CSS file by parsing your code and including only fully-formed (non-dynamic) utility classes. For an explanation, see: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

If the possible `percentage1` and `percentage2` values range from 0 to 100, it's probably best to divide the value by 100 and use a `style` attribute instead of Tailwind for the transform CSS. For example:

```
<div style={{transform: `scaleX(${percentage1/100})`}} className="absolute inset-0 w-full origin-top-left bg-indigo-500 bg-opacity-50"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/scale), `10` is not a predefined value for the `scale` class. To add a [one off custom value](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/scale#arbitrary-values), you can do the following:

```js
className={`scale-x-[${percentage1}]`}
```

`0` is 0%, while `1` is 100%.

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't work. 
    className={`scale-x-[${percentage1}] absolute inset-0 w-full origin-top-left bg- 
    indigo-500 bg-opacity-50`}